# Custom HTTP Status code not working in Sever

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-7, http-status-codes

I have changed the `HTTP` status code in my `json` response using `Laravel`. It's working fine in `localhost` but the same code not working  `WHM` server.

Laravel Version : 7

PHP Version : 7.4

My code

```
$encode = ['code' => 400,'message'  => 'Token is Invalid','data' => []];
return Response::make(json_encode($encode,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_FORCE_OBJECT),401)->header('Content-Type',"application/json");
```

**Local host Response**

[image]

**Server Response**
[image]

Please anyone help to resolve this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

i don't worked with laravel so can't help you about laravel

but you can solve your problem self with php

set your http code via header

```
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
```

Comment: This also return the same response.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
   $response = ['code' => 401,'message'  => 'Token is Invalid','data' => []];
   return response($response, 401);
```

Comment: so problem is about your server and your php build. test it in another server (not local machines)